# how to copy one column(only single column) at a time into another sheet of same excel workbook

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

According to requirement I need to copy few columns like A1 S1 K1 from one excel sheet to another in the same excel workbook.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: i tried using range that is working fine. but that will increase my work I have to delete the extra columns and then comparing with other excel data

Comment: anybody Please help me. need to submit by monday. thanks in advance

Comment: You have a better chance of getting help if you show what you have already.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select a cell in the column you wish to copy.
2. Press Ctrl+space (as in the space bar!). This selects the entire column.
3. Press Ctrl+C. This is the keyboard shortcut for **Copy**.
4. Move to the other sheet. Select a cell **IN ROW ONE** where you want the copied data to appear.
5. Press Ctrl+V. This is the keyboard shortcut for **Paste**.

I feel quite certain that this is not what you *need*. However, it answers the question you *asked*.